# Excel: Separate text in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to seperate a field into two by finding the values that are in the left of an asterisk and then what's on the right.

For example
Cell **C1** is `0A*33` then **C2** should be `0A` and **C3** should be `33`.

I have the following formulas in cells C2 and C3:

`=LEFT(C1,SEARCH("~*",C1,1)-1)`

`=RIGHT(C1,LEN(A3)-SEARCH("~*",C1,1))`

These formulas work great as long as there is a asterisk in the cell, if not it results in a **#VALUE!** error.

I have even tried (For the left side) `=LEFT(C1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("~*",C1,1)-1),C1,SEARCH("~*",C1,1)-1))` with the same outcome.

If the cell does not have an asterisk it must return the whole value in **C2** and nothing in cell **C3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:
In C2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",C1)),C1,LEFT(C1,FIND("*",C1)-1))
```

In C3:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",C1)),"",RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND("*",C1)))
```

You could use the same idea with `SEARCH`, but `FIND` works fine in this case:

In C2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("~*",C1,1)),C1,LEFT(C1,SEARCH("~*",C1,1)-1))
```

In C3:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("~*",C1,1)),"",RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-SEARCH("~*",C1,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(C1,FIND("*",C1&"*")-1)
=MID(C1,FIND("*",C1&"*")+1,255)
```

Comment: Another method without using formulas is: select C1 then choose Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next... Other : * > Next... Destination: D1.